# Shuffling two NSMutableArrays in a predictable manner

Tags: objective-c

I have two NSMutableArrays of strings that I wish to combine and shuffle together. However, I want it so that every time it shuffles the original two arrays, it always yields the same array in the same order. How can this be done?

Could I seed some constant value into the random function like in C++ `srand(constant)` but in Objective-C?

Edit: Or say I just have one array (not sure if this makes any difference) and I wanted to shuffle that one array in a predictable manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is just to do `srandom(constant)` and use the `random()` function in Objective C. This way you'll always get the same shuffle and random values.